# load a image, css, or js file via php

Tags: php

i am making my own framework and would like to allow easy direct access to a asset file such an image, a javascript or a css file.

currently I'm attempting to allow the use of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css" />
```

I have my .htaccess file capture the URI and allow me to manipulate it with PHP.

My router class captures the uri and detects the actual path to the file. So my question is how do i write it up in PHP?

```
public function router($file)
{
    //output assets file here
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What are you trying to achieve (larger picture)? Is there any particular reason why you need PHP here?

Comment: Why make your poor webserver run PHP, open a file, read it, and write it out, instead of just letting it give out the file automatically?

Comment: because other wise i would need to access a file like `/application/myapp/assets/css/style.css` when I can just access it via `/assets/css/style.css` And the application is dynamically filled in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function router($file) {
    // Only do this if the file is a valid type to be outputted;
    // It would be bad if someone started viewing your PHP.
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        readfile($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: readfile use the ouput buffer so its possible that you have some error messages in the image return. "file_get_contents()" is a better solution in this case.

Comment: Are you proposing that I insert a `if (file_exists($file))` statement?

Comment: so file_get_contents() is the how to do it?

Comment: @Eli: Same as readfile but you get realy the data and no other things from the output buffer.